# Subjecting multiple dependent variables to multiple models, to produce a dataframe of list columns

Tags: tidyverse, purrr, lm, mutate

I've got a long hand way of applying each of a set of models to nested data, while giving each list-column output a sensible name in the tibble.  I have a lot of models though, and want to have a more slick, vectorised way of doing this rather than writing it out.  I'm stumbling over getting the column names to be dynamically assigned.

What I'm aiming for, is a single tibble with a row for each dependent variable, where the first column is the character vector of the dependent variables, and each subsequent column is a list column of the lm's named accordingly.  Here's a reprex I hope is useful to explain:

```r
library(reprex)
library(tidyverse)

rm(list=ls())
data <- mtcars |>
  mutate(c1  = rbinom(nrow(mtcars),prob=0.05, size = 1),
         c2 = rbinom(nrow(mtcars), prob = 0.1, size =1),
         c3 = rbinom(nrow(mtcars), prob = 0.5, size = 1))


candidates <- c("c1","c2","c3")
covars <- c("disp","hp","drat","wt")
outcomes <- c("mpg","qsec")

outcome_cols <- names(data)[names(data) %in% outcomes]

dat_long <- data |>
  pivot_longer(cols=all_of(outcome_cols), names_to = "outcome", values_to = "value")

dat_n <- dat_long |>
  group_by(cyl) |>
  nest()

c_models <- c("c1_mod","c2_mod","c3_mod")

c1_mod <- function(df){
  lm(value ~ c1 + disp + hp, data = df)
}

c2_mod <- function(df){
  lm(value ~ c2 + disp + drat, data = df)
}

c3_mod <- function(df){
  lm(value ~ c3 + drat + wt, data = df)
}

# previous long hand way to apply each model to each outcome 

dat_n <- dat_n |>
  mutate(c1 = map(data, c1_mod),
         c2 = map(data, c2_mod),
         c3 = map(data, c3_mod))

# trying to wrap the above into something more slick ... not working

mapfun <- function(mod, dat_n) {
  dat_n <- dat_n |>
    mutate(mod = map(data, mod))
}

for (i in 1:length(c_models)){
  mapfun(i, dat_n)
}
```

I've also been trying to use quosures and symbols etc, but I feel like i making things more complicated than they need to be.  Help!

```
  dat_n <- dat_n |>
    mutate(mod = map(data, mod))
}

for (i in 1:length(c_models)){
  mapfun(i, dat_n)
}
```

Did not find any helpful posts on SO and elsewhere, as I need to use `purrr::map` iteratively.

Answer (score 0):

So after a LOT of googling and trying odd things, this now works:
If I have a set of models, which each are named according to a character vector called modelsets, I then run:

```
#Create the function to map each model to the data column and name it according to the model used
addmodels <- function(col, dat_n){
  dat_n<- dat_n|>
    mutate({{col}} := map(data,  models[modelsets== col]))
}

#Apply that function to each element of the `modelsets` list
b <- map(modelsets, addmodels, dat_n)

#Then combine the results into a new data frame.
bo <- b |>
  reduce(inner_join, by=c("outcome","data"))
```

Knew there was a succinct answer to be found! Although I'm sure this could be improved upon.